# Drupal: taxonomy filter from separate view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

this is my first website in Drupal 7, I'm trying to learn this framework, but I'm encountering a problem to which I could not find a solution yet.

I'm trying to create a page with a panel that has 2 views (as seen in [this photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ep72wnpah42mdv3/site_layout.jpg?dl=0)), the left view contains a list of categories (terms from taxonomy) and the right view contains a list/grid of projects (Content Type). Each project is of a single category and when I click on a category on the left side I want it to filter only the projects of that category on the right side, in the same page (or a new page with the same layout ../projects/category_term_1).

What happens now is that when I click on a category, I'm taken to a page that diplays the projects listed as taxonony term ( ../taxonomy/nr_taxonomy) different layout (like blog, but without categories on the left side).

I have aces to another project where the functionality that I want is implemented is a sort of similar type of pages.  I tried to replicate all configuration from that site to mine, but the only difference that I'm able to notice is that the value of "STORAGE" column the administration/structure/pages is "normal" for my website and "in code" for the other site.

Site's layout:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ep72wnpah42mdv3/site_layout.jpg?dl=0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main view should use a [contextual filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65525/how-to-pass-views-contextual-filter-via-url), based in the URL given. This way, the view would only show those projects in the specified category.

In the left view, you should show the taxonomy terms, but you should modify the URL given with your custom one: www.example.com/projects/taxonomyTerm

Hope it helps